# How to append repeated element inside different parents in another element in the same parents

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have tried to remove repeated elements in different parent elements and append them to another elements in the same parents using `JQuery` but it doesn't work correctly

Here is the `HTML` code:

```
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <h1> Text 1 </h1>
  </div>
  <span> data 1 </span>
</div>
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <h1> Text 2 </h1>
  </div>
  <span> data 2 </span>
</div>
```

Here is the `JQuery` code used

```
$('span').each(function(){
  $(this).appendTo('.inner');
});
```

The result is here on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pczs/27/)

I need to the result to be like that:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1> Text 1 </h1>
    <span> data 1 </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1> Text 1 </h1>
    <span> data 1 </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By just using a blind `$('.inner')` selector, you're selecting both inner divs. You should use `siblings()` to select only the inner div closest to the element being used.

Your code should be:

```
$('span').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo($(this).siblings('.inner'));
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8Pczs/29/)

In cases where the element and its target destination aren't actually siblings, an alternative would be:

```
$('span').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.outer').find('.inner'));
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8Pczs/30/)

Comment: Check the result of JSFiddle source code again it doesn't work